# Is there a way to fix Cluster-SSH windows positions automatically?

Tags: linux, ssh, graphical-user-interface, windows-cluster

Have you used Cluster-SSH? It's a GUI (frontend) to secure shell (ssh) which function it's to let you write the very same commands to a lot of hosts. If you open a lot of hosts at the same time, cluster-ssh opens a window for each one of them. But these windows don't actually are perfectly ordered in the screen, I mean the same size and not overlapping. I always have to resize and move manually every windows to some kind of grid so I can see every terminal output at the same time.

Is there a way to tell cluster-ssh to order the generated windows in the size/position needed in some kind of configuration file??? If so, HOW?

I do this often with a lot of hosts, so I don't want to lose time arranging the windows as I need, I use Linux =) Thanks a lot =)

**EDIT:** This is a complement of the answer with a helpful tip. Even with the correct answer, it wasn't so easy for me to align the windows just as I wanted =/
If you get an error as this one:

```
$ cssh host1 host2
Illegal division by zero at /usr/share/perl5/App/ClusterSSH.pm line 1258, <CLUSTERS> line 3.
```

Just change the value of `terminal_size` to something lower.

Also at first I didn't notice any change at all in the size of the windows. I noticed that (al least in Ubuntu 11.04 + KDE environment) retiling the windows it's useless. In order to apply the resize, you must minimize all terminals and ten retile. That way the real size it's applied. I don't know why this behavior. A bug maybe?

Greetings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cssh is supposed to tile the windows automatically. Try adding the following to `~/.csshrc` (the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/cssh.1p.html#contenttoc7) contains all the options):

```
terminal_size = 80x24
console_position = +0+0
window_tiling = yes
always_tile = yes
```

Comment: UPS! I did open the man but I didn't read that section THANKS =)

Comment: I use XFCE4 with a panel at the top of the screen. To account for this, I needed the `screen_reserve_top=` option, otherwise the first row of terminals overlaps the 2nd row of terminals.

Comment: Note that the config is now located at ~/.clusterssh/config

Comment: Beware, `console_position` is only do move the position of the box where you type commands, not offsetting the terminals. (@bobpaul's suggestion helped me though)